# How can I delete whole word in command insert mode?

Tags: normal-mode

Following my pressing ':' I can switch to command insert mode and pressing 'Up Arrow' I can bring up my previous command. 
How can I delete a word left of my cursor during command insert mode?
Say for my example I have this in my command pane:

```
:!sh listtablefromdb.sh mytablename
```

I would like to delete `mytablename` via single keyboard shortcut

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> all characters to the left of the cursor until the beginning of the commandline will be deleted. This is also explained in the help at 
[:h c_CTRL-U](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-U)

To delete a single word, you can use <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd>([:h c_CTRL-W](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-W))

Comment: Use `Ctrl-W` to delete a single word

Comment: Use `q:` or `<c-f>` to open the command-line window to unleash even more power! See `:h cmdwin`

Comment: how do I delete a word/line to the right in insert mode?

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> will delete one word.